# How to know when request completes successfully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We have an action which is used by a mobile application to download a Job.  Once a job has been downloaded, it is marked as such, so that next time round the app doesn't ask for the job again.  We need to know when the entire HTTP request has completed successfully, and only then should we mark the job as 'downloaded'.  Because the app is mobile, it may be that half way through sending the data to the client, the connection resets - but we have marked the job as downloaded, e.g.:

```
Client request starts
Mark job as downloaded
render view
Sending data
xxxx - connection fails
```

Ideally we want it 'transactional' such that:

```
Client request starts
render view
Sending data
All Data sent, request is complete
Mark job as downloaded
```

Is this possible using rails? It appears that an after_filter runs BEFORE the actual response data is sent to the client - is there any sort of filter that runs after the entire HTTP request between client and server is complete?

Thanks, M

Comment: I think you should find the solution on the client side. Your client knows when it has downloaded the complete job. When that happens, send a request to your server indicating the job is downloaded. You can then store markt it as downloaded on your server.